# With Google Places API, how do I get all places in a rectangular zone?

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

For a mobile application, I would like to get all places included in a map screen view (hence the rectangular zone).

[image]

---

Reading the API's documentation, I found out that [Find Place requests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#FindPlaceRequests) can use a rectangular location bias, but only answer with one place; on the other hand, [Text Search requests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests) return several places, but do not have rectangular location bias; moreover, both need some input text, which I don't want to provide.

Which request type is the best to match my problem? *(maybe Places API offers a suitable request I don't know about)*

Comment: 1) It's a bias, not a proper restriction 2) All the available API endpoints are documented on the page you linked 3) Results are anyway restricted to a maximum of 20 results (with one request) + 40 additional results using pagination.

Answer (score -2):

Hey you could define a zone using latlong then use the [Nearby Search Requests](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests)

and it should give you all places in that zone

Comment: Please don't use link only answer. Please provide some example with context. In the future the link may not work, and your answer would be useless